# derive $\lim\inf$ property from convergence statement

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a positive function $f(x)$ and I know the following

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log{f(x)}}{x}=0$$

why does this imply that $$\lim\inf_{x\to\infty}f(x)\exp{(r x)}>0$$

for a positive $r>0$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the first property tells me that the $\log f(x)$ is growing or declining slower than $\frac{1}{x}$. I would have said this implies taht $f(x)$ is growing or declining slower than $\exp{(-x)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $-\frac {\log f(x)} x \leq |\frac {\log f(x)} x| <\epsilon$ for $x$ sufficiently large. Hence, $f(x) >e^{-\epsilon x}$ for such $x$. Take $0<\epsilon <r$.